# What set does $\mathbb{S}^d$ refer to?

Tags: notation

I've seen [one answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-does-mathbb-S-mathbb-R-d-mean-in-mathematics?share=1) saying $\mathbb{S}^d$ the set of bijective functions from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to itself, but haven't found any corroboration for this.

I'm specifically looking at [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.00686.pdf) (page 2 above Eq. 1). Any ideas what it means in this context?

Comment: [sphere ?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold)

Comment: Usually, this means the d-dimensional sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ is another notation for the $(d-1$)-sphere $S^{d-1} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^d:\, |x| = 1\}$.  The paragraph following that equation mentions that $\theta\in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ is a "direction."

Comment: Should be $x \in \mathbb R^{d-1}$, no?

Comment: No. The $n$-sphere naturally sits inside $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. (Cf. the circle in the plane.)